# Using Entry to search through a number of entries in a Listbox (tkinter)

Tags: python, search, tkinter, listbox, tkinter-entry

I want to use a search function which searches through a list of program names (chrome, thunderbird, adobe reader etc.)

I have a Listbox and then a load of program names added into the Listbox, I want the search feature, entry_1, to search through all of these names and then highlight the one which was searched for.

Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```html
from tkinter import *

    
#definitions
root = Tk()
var_1 = StringVar(root)
label_1 = Label(root, text="Search:")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Subject specific programs below")
label_3 = Label(root, text="Subject:")
entry_1 = Entry(root) #this should search through the strings listed under listbox_2 configs
button_1 = Button(root, text="Install")
scrollbar_1 = Scrollbar(root)
listbox_2 = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_1.set)
optionmenu_1 = OptionMenu(root, var_1, "Computing", "Engineering", "Physics")
string_1 = StringVar(root, name="Google Chrome")
string_2 = StringVar(root, name="Thunderbird")
string_3 = StringVar(root, name="Adobe Reader X")
string_4 = StringVar(root, name="WinRAR")
string_5 = StringVar(root, name="OpenOffice")
string_6 = StringVar(root, name="Program 1")
string_7 = StringVar(root, name="Program 2")
string_8 = StringVar(root, name="Program 3")
string_9 = StringVar(root, name="Program 4")
string_10 = StringVar(root, name="Program 5")
string_11 = StringVar(root, name="Program 6")

#configuration
root.title("Network Installation")
listbox_2.insert(1, string_1)
listbox_2.insert(2, string_2)
listbox_2.insert(3, string_3)
listbox_2.insert(4, string_4)
listbox_2.insert(5, string_5)
listbox_2.insert(6, string_6)
listbox_2.insert(7, string_7)
listbox_2.insert(8, string_8)
listbox_2.insert(9, string_9)
listbox_2.insert(10, string_10)
listbox_2.insert(11, string_11)
optionmenu_1.config(width=15)
scrollbar_1.config(command=listbox_2.yview)

#grid additions
label_1.grid(row=0, column=5)
label_2.grid(columnspan=6, row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=6)
button_1.grid(columnspan=2, row=7, column=5)
listbox_2.grid(rowspan=6, columnspan=6, row=2, column=0)
scrollbar_1.grid(rowspan=6, row=2, column=4, sticky=N+S)
optionmenu_1.grid(columnspan=3, row=0, column=1)
label_3.grid(row=0, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far? What part of the problem or solution don't you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure how I reply to you, but so far I haven't tried anything because i'm not sure how you would use Entry for this purpose. I also don't even know if i've set it up right, but my main problem is not knowing where to start. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a long time ago but here's how to highlight the listbox items using a search entry box in Tkinter.

Explanation:

1. `all_listbox_items` is the most important part. When the program first populates the listbox, it's important to capture those initial values and use the search entry box as a way to query these initial entries.
2. add a `textvariable` to `entry_1` and name it `search_var`.
3. put a trace on `search_var` so if the values in the `entry_1` change, we can trigger a function named `highlight_searched`.
4. The function `highlight_searched` basically `enumerates` all the listbox items and checks to see if the searched text in `entry_1` is in any of the items from the listbox. Where this is true, you use `selection_set(i)` (where i is short-hand for index) to select each item.

I'm not particularly happy with using enumerate. It's just easy. There surely is a better way to return the index of an item in a for loop. I'd love to hear a better solution to my enumeration suggestion.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

#definitions
root = Tk()
var_1 = StringVar(root)
label_1 = Label(root, text="Search:")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Subject specific programs below")
label_3 = Label(root, text="Subject:")

def highlight_searched(*args):
  search = search_var.get()
  for i,item in enumerate(all_listbox_items):
    if search.lower() in item.lower():
      listbox_2.selection_set(i)
    else:
      listbox_2.selection_clear(i)
  if search == '':
    listbox_2.selection_clear(0, END)

search_var = StringVar()
search_var.trace('w', highlight_searched)
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=search_var) #this should search through the strings listed under listbox_2 configs

button_1 = Button(root, text="Install")
scrollbar_1 = Scrollbar(root)
listbox_2 = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_1.set)
optionmenu_1 = OptionMenu(root, var_1, "Computing", "Engineering", "Physics")
string_1 = StringVar(root, name="Google Chrome")
string_2 = StringVar(root, name="Thunderbird")
string_3 = StringVar(root, name="Adobe Reader X")
string_4 = StringVar(root, name="WinRAR")
string_5 = StringVar(root, name="OpenOffice")
string_6 = StringVar(root, name="Program 1")
string_7 = StringVar(root, name="Program 2")
string_8 = StringVar(root, name="Program 3")
string_9 = StringVar(root, name="Program 4")
string_10 = StringVar(root, name="Program 5")
string_11 = StringVar(root, name="Program 6")

#configuration
root.title("Network Installation")
listbox_2.insert(1, string_1)
listbox_2.insert(2, string_2)
listbox_2.insert(3, string_3)
listbox_2.insert(4, string_4)
listbox_2.insert(5, string_5)
listbox_2.insert(6, string_6)
listbox_2.insert(7, string_7)
listbox_2.insert(8, string_8)
listbox_2.insert(9, string_9)
listbox_2.insert(10, string_10)
listbox_2.insert(11, string_11)
optionmenu_1.config(width=15)
scrollbar_1.config(command=listbox_2.yview)

#grid additions
label_1.grid(row=0, column=5)
label_2.grid(columnspan=6, row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=6)
button_1.grid(columnspan=2, row=7, column=5)
listbox_2.grid(rowspan=6, columnspan=6, row=2, column=0)
scrollbar_1.grid(rowspan=6, row=2, column=4, sticky=N+S)
optionmenu_1.grid(columnspan=3, row=0, column=1)
label_3.grid(row=0, column=0)

all_listbox_items = listbox_2.get(0, END)

root.mainloop()
```

And anyone showing up to this question that might be looking for a search box that filters the listbox (as opposed to highlighting them like this question is asking) to show only the relevant items pertaining to the search, you can use this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def update_listbox(*args):
  search_term = search_var.get()
  listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
  for item in all_items:
    if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
      listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

search_var = tk.StringVar()
search_var.trace('w', update_listbox)
searchbox = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=search_var)
searchbox.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
for i in ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob']:
  listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
listbox.pack()
all_items = listbox.get(0, tk.END)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent answer Jarad. If instead of 11 items, one had thousands of items in the listbox and one searched for a phrase that appeared close to the bottom of list, how would you modify the code so that the listbox would automatically scroll down to where it found the phrase in some item in the list?